# MPMediaItemCollection Whole Library?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mpmediaitem, mpmediaitemcollection

Does anyone know if it's possible to create an MPMediaItemCollection object containing every song in a users iPod library without the user having to select it using the MPMediaPicker stuff? Like, on application launch perhaps.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
    MPMediaQuery *everything = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];

    NSArray *songs = [everything items];
    MPMediaItemCollection *mediaCollection = [MPMediaItemCollection collectionWithItems:songs];
    [everything release];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// _musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];

MPMediaQuery *allLibrary = [[MPMediaQuery alloc]init];
[allLibrary setGroupingType:MPMediaGroupingTitle];
[_musicPlayer setQueueWithQuery:allLibrary];
```